# Matrix transition Maolusce

Tags: qgis, molusce

I'm having problems with Molusce pluging. The rasters have same cell size, coordinate sytem and extension. My problem is that I get the transition Matrix but the information,  according my experience is not correct. The highest values should be in the columns with the same land cover that in the files.

This picture shows that the urban land cover has the highest values in Suelo Desnudo and I'm almost sure that isn't correct. The goal is to know in which land cover has made the transition every land cover.

Why is this happening?

[image]